# Nodejs MaxListenersExceededWarning limited stacktrace inside aws lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, memory-leaks, aws-lambda

I am using nodejs 8.10 in AWS lambda with API-Gateway. I am getting MaxListenersExceededWarning. I tried `process.setMaxListeners(0);` in app.js of express app.  but still, warnings are there. 
To get more detail I have added this into my code.

```
process.on('warning', (warning) => {
  console.log("[+] Warning ", JSON.stringify(warning));
  console.log(warning.name); // Print the warning name
  console.log(warning.message); // Print the warning message
  console.log(warning.stack); // Print the stack trace
});
```

but stack and everything have very limited information.

```
{
    "name": "MaxListenersExceededWarning",
    "emitter": {
        "fetching": false,
        "_events": {
            "value": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ]
        },
        "_eventsCount": 1
    },
    "type": "value",
    "count": 11
}
```

It's not telling me at which place specifically error is there. also, this error is not available locally it's only in production so I don't think so there is a way to add --stack-trace in production lambda.